# Why did the strict rules of evidence result in a debt being due twice, even though common law dismissed this as absurd?

Tags: england-and-wales, equity

As "*the common
law held that a debt was due twice . . . [that proposition] would have been dismissed as
absurd*", why wasn't this the end of the story for the debtor? Why was this "*the result which followed from observing strict rules of evidence*"?

I am befuddled by the modal verb "**might**" in quotation beneath. Did the rules of evidence truly  "*exclude the merits of the case from consideration but which could not be relaxed without destroying certainty and condoning carelessness*"?

Most lawyers and judges are crafty. I am startled that even they could not skirt, outjockey, and/or relax the rules of evidence in order to actualize  a common law proposition dismissed as absurd ("a debt was due twice")

> 1.5 The first is that equity, fairness, or justice were never absent from the common law
> courts. The difference was that from the mid-fourteenth century the complaints that the
> common law courts would hear became fixed. That is, the common law courts refused to
> invent new categories of writs, or different ‘forms of action’; the procedures of the court
> as to pleading and evidence also became fixed. Baker (2002), at 102–103 (slightly modified)
> illustrates the sort of problem that could arise because of this:
>
> > [T]he growing strength of the substantive law could also work injustice, because the
> > judges preferred to suffer hardship in individual cases than to make exceptions to clear
> > rules. The stock example was that of the debtor who gave his creditor a sealed bond
> > [a paper document recording the obligation to pay the debt], but did not ensure that it
> > was cancelled when he paid up. The law regarded the bond as incontrovertible evidence
> > of the debt, and so payment was no defence. Here the debtor would suffer an obvious
> > hardship if he was made to pay twice; but the mischief was a result of his own foolishness,
> > and the law did not bend to protect fools . . . **Now it was not that the common
> > law held that a debt was due twice . . . [that proposition] would have been dismissed as
> > absurd. Yet that was the result which followed from observing strict rules of evidence,
> > rules which might exclude the merits of the case from consideration but which could not
> > be relaxed without destroying certainty and condoning carelessness. [emphasis added]**

On page 4 of *The Law of Trusts* 12th edn (2022), James Penner quoted  Baker, J. H. (2002). *An Introduction to English
Legal History*, 4th Ed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "rule which might exclude the merits of the case from consideration" referred to in this passage is the rule that "a sealed bond [was] incontrovertible evidence of the debt, and so payment was no defence."

Strict application of a rule about "incontrovertible evidence" can result in absurdity when the proposition which is legally "incontrovertible" – in this case, that the debt evidenced by the sealed bond continued to exist – is actually false. [From falsehood, anything follows.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion)